# rod technical name

Tags: mechanical-engineering, product-engineering

Does anyone knows what is the name of this rod? are these available in the market?[image]

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a piece of plain 1/2" or 5/8" steel rod with locking collars on its ends.

Comment: Looks a bit large for 1/2 inch... 7/8 may be..

Answer (score 1):

This could be called a « locking pin » or « locating pin » or « sliding stop » , depends on the function but most would understand the function and form.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of work-out bench called " Rogue Adjustable Bench."

As you can see in the photo this Pin is to adjust the angle of the bench. This is a fitness company's brochure photo I used.

there is more info [here](https://www.roguefitness.com/rogue-adjustable-bench-2-0)

[image]

Comment: Nice picture, but no name for the pin...

Comment: One could contact the manifacturer and ask for the pin name! I have included a link to their page. BTW there are two pins on this bench to adjust the angle. But by scaling from the given dimension it seems to be a 3/4 inch rod.